Running a program/script before a user logs in on RedHat Linux GUI
I am looking to run a script prior to a user being able to log in on the GUI.
Its a basic script, do you accept Ts&Cs Y/N, enter user name, data is captured and stored. Then once complete takes them to the log in screen.
My issue is I am unsure where or how this would run (being relatively new to Linux and scripting). I have searched and played about with gdm in terms of just displaying a user agreement when logging in but I would like to create something the user has to interact with.
Any pointers on where and how to start would be appreciated.

Wouldn't you need to run this after they log in? Otherwise you don't know who they are, so you can't record who agreed to the T&C.

My thought was, if they enter their Username then that would give the same outcome. However, running it after could achieve the same goal, if they agree Y then continue log in, if N then return to log in screen.
